# jQuery tabs are not working in IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-tabs

I am using jQuery Tabs in an asp mvc 2 application.

Previously my code worked in all browsers(i.e the tabs were working well):

```
<ul class="tab-menu">
        <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetCoreTab", "ModalPopup") %>" class="a" title="Reservation Details"><b>
            <div id="home" class="menu">
            </div>
        </b></a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetDatesAndLocationTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
            <div id="dates-and-location" class="menu">
            </div>
        </b></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Now I changed the list code (to a new requirement). And now the tabs do not work in IE 7 and 8.(i.e the views for all the tabs appear in the first tab)

Here is the modified code:

```
<ul class="tab-menu">
        <li><a href="#GetCoreTab" class="a"><b>
            <div id="home" class="menu">
            </div>
        </b></a></li>
        <li><a href="#GetCustomerInformationTab" class="a"><b>
            <div id="customer-information" class="menu">
            </div>
        </b></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="GetCoreTab">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("Editors/Reservation/Tabs/TabCore"); %>
    </div>
    <div id="GetCustomerInformationTab">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("Editors/Reservation/Tabs/TabCustomerInformation"); %>
    </div>
```

Please do not tell me to use the previous version of the code since it is not possible. I just need to make the second version working in IE7 and 8, since it works well in Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks